# How to sign my APK file in release mode

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I am developed one app and i have deleted all log.d and all other log's.
I also changed in manifest file "Debuggable=False",then i again cleaned my  project and test it on device.after that i have created the keystore using export wizard & then created a zipaligned apk file using CMD.

But now still am not able to upload it,it showing the error as:
"You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode."

Please can any one tell me how to make .apk as release mode in eclipse ADT.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: its not work in eclipse adt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [android signing your application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) generate a keystore and attach it to your application

- Right click on your project
- go to export -> android -> Export android application -> next
- then it will show your project
- Create new key store
  here you have give the name of the keystore file extension is  .**jks**
  and password (this keystore file should be kept safe  cause every time when you release update of your app you should sign with this **keystore** and remember the **password**)
- fill the details in next page
- destination location of your apk file .

Follow the steps

Comment: how to attach it with my application

Comment: you using eclipse or studio ?

Comment: @sahil follow the following steps.. extension of release file will be same .apk.. keystore file extension is .jks

Comment: and upload the apk file which is generated ,its signed and do check for every functionality

Comment: by following steps at last when it ask for the "Destination and key/ certificate checks " at this window, what extension should i give to file?

Comment: its the location of your apk file and the extension will be .apk (it will generate your signed apk file in that place ) eg /Desktop/yourapp.apk.. Now yourapp.apk will be your apk file

Answer (score 1):

Go to:-

```
Right click on project-> Android tools-> Export Signed APK.
```

Follow to the credentials of keystore and its done.

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Also chk that pckg name should not be com.example.abc

Comment: do you get any apk now?

Comment: its not apk file but it showing as release file with same size as apk file.

Comment: what is the extension of that file?

Comment: am just started using this site and my reputation are not more so that am unable to chat

Comment: extension of file is     RELEASE File (.release)

Comment: while moving through keystore you have asked to set path for apk in last step. the path which you have set, there you find the apk.